# Chat https redirects to http

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks, ssl

Yes, yes, I know https isn't officially supported.

If you go to a chat room link like https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1 (note that there isn't a room name), it would automatically redirect the page to the canon URL (with the room name included). However, that redirects to the http:// version of the page.

This makes bookmarking https URLs of chat rooms very difficult, as room names often change for various reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed next deploy