# Changing room names causes https version to change to http automatically

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, ssl

This is related to my other [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [Chat https redirects to http](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242937/chat-https-redirects-to-http), but it's a bit different.

When you are in a room under https, if the room changes name, the browser automatically refreshes the page to get the next changes. But it will redirect to the http version of the page silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro the redirect issue; however, unless I'm missing something I simply can't see something that is automatically refreshing here. It *seems* to simply continue with the wrong url. I'll deploy chat in a few minutes; can you let me know whether this still continues?

Comment: Thanks, seems to have been fixed in this deployment.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I wonder if the "no repro" was because I'm using web-sockets and perhaps you are using poll (or the other way around). Either way: I'm glad it is fixed.